# Moving a SKPhysics Body on touches by applying force on a point on body

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I am moving the physics body by changing its velocity in `update`. The body is moving, but this gives an unrealistic movement as in it simply changes its position , there is no angular movement around the point holding the body due to gravity or air friction. On looking further in Apple developer's guide, for movement of a Physics body :

> A force applied to a point on the body. The physics simulation
>   calculates separate changes to the body’s angular and linear velocity,
>   based on the shape of the object and the point where the force was
>   applied.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this realistic movement with angular movement also along the touch point on body by applying a force?
Current code for movement by updating velocity :

```
static const CGFloat kPlayerMovementSpeed = 50.0f;

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    self.touchLocation=[touch locationInNode:self];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    self.touchLocation = location;
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
if (itemHeld && refNode)
  {
    refNode.physicsBody.velocity=CGVectorMake(0, 0);
    CGFloat distance = hypotf(refNode.position.x - self.touchLocation.x, refNode.position.y - self.touchLocation.y);
    CGFloat damping = sqrt(distance * kPlayerMovementSpeed);

    if (damping < 0)
    {
        damping = 0.0f;
    }

    refNode.physicsBody.linearDamping = damping;
    refNode.physicsBody.angularDamping = damping;

    CGPoint bodyPos = refNode.position;
    CGPoint translation = CGPointMake(self.touchLocation.x - bodyPos.x, self.touchLocation.y - bodyPos.y);
    CGVector velocityVector=CGVectorMake(translation.x * kPlayerMovementSpeed,
                                         translation.y * kPlayerMovementSpeed);
    refNode.physicsBody.velocity = velocityVector;
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for your node to rotate at all? Or do you simply want more realistic linear velocity?

Comment: I want both realistic linear and angular movement , like if i am picking a pen from one end , its other end should hang down due to gravity , that ways how to apply force on just a touch point for movement.